# TypeError: Super expression must either be null or a function, not undefined when using react-csv in Nextjs

Tags: next.js

I want to add the download csv function to my Nextjs application, sample code on app/page.tsx:

```js
import { CSVLink } from 'react-csv';

export default function Home() {
  const csvData = [
    ["firstname", "lastname", "email"],
    ["Ahmed", "Tomi", "ah@smthing.co.com"],
    ["Raed", "Labes", "rl@smthing.co.com"],
    ["Yezzi", "Min l3b", "ymin@cocococo.com"],
  ];

  return (
    <div>
      <CSVLink data={csvData}>Download me</CSVLink>
    </div>
  );
}
```

However, I got the error:

```
 ⨯ node_modules/react-csv/lib/components/Download.js (23:112) @ _inherits
 ⨯ TypeError: Super expression must either be null or a function, not undefined
    at _inherits (webpack-internal:///(rsc)/./node_modules/react-csv/lib/components/Download.js:43:15)
    at eval (webpack-internal:///(rsc)/./node_modules/react-csv/lib/components/Download.js:59:5)
    at eval (webpack-internal:///(rsc)/./node_modules/react-csv/lib/components/Download.js:94:2)
...
  digest: '2432728574',
  page: '/'
}
null
```

When I add the `use client` on top of it, it works without the above error, but I need to use [async function](https://nextjs.org/docs/app/building-your-application/data-fetching/fetching-caching-and-revalidating) to fetch the data, therefore can not use `use client`.

How can I fix this issue, any suggestion?